# How to group table data using php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to search the internet and tried several php arrays and loops (foreach, UNIQUE etc) and different approach but ended up no luck. I guess I just can't get the right approach.Please I need your help to figure it out.

Basically I have product and img files table where one product has several image files and I want to display or echo the data in such a way that the image files are all together in one div based on product id.

[Image Files Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyBX6.png)

The recent code I have tried was:

```
$result_img = "SELECT * FROM product, img_files
    WHERE product.prod_id = img_files.prod_id AND img_files.cover = '1'
    GROUP BY img_files.img_name ORDER BY img_files.prod_id";
$run_query_img = mysqli_query($con, $result_img);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query_img)) {
    $img_name = $row['img_name'];
    $prod_name = $row['prod_name'];

    echo "<p>$prod_name<br>$img_name</p><br>";

}
```

**Yet the result I am getting is:**

"Monogram Door Knocker
knocker.jpg /

Monogram Door Knocker
knocker1.jpg /

Gauze Pillow
thr_pillow2.jpg /

Gauze Pillow
thr_pillow.jpg /
"

**what I wanted to have is:**

Monogram Door Knocker
knocker.jpg
knocker1.jpg /

Gauze Pillow
thr_pillow2.jpg
thr_pillow.jpg /

Comment: Did you also try `GROUP_CONCAT`? https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: coud you give the create command to tables product and img_files ?

Comment: without the contents of both tables your question can not be answered

Comment: who is img_files.cover ?